# Accessing Email templates in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Hi i created an object in which onefield is lookup to user and other field is id of email template .
i have to create a visualforce page in which i have to assign different email templates to different users and then save  records of custom object. can u please tell me how to get all email templates Name and id created in MyTemplates  in picklist of VF page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX CONTROLLER

```
public class TemplateSelectorController {

    public String selectedTemplateId { public get; public set; }

    public List<SelectOption> getMyPersonalTemplateOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (EmailTemplate t : [
            select Id,Name 
            from EmailTemplate
            // Each User has a 'My Personal Templates' folder
            // of EmailTemplates, whose Id is the User's Id
            where FolderId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        ]) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id,t.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

VISUALFORCE PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="TemplateSelectorController">
     <apex:form>
         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTemplateId}">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!myPersonalTemplateOptions}"/>
         </apex:selectList>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @ zachelrath :i am not where u define the folder name as suppose i have folde name Lead 360 thn how can pull the templates as well as in vf page u mention this   <apex:selectOptions value="{!myPersonalTemplateOptions}"/> but in class i am nt getting it.

Comment: @Deepakmahajan, in this case change your "where" clause to be "where Folder.Name = 'Lead 360'" so that you're pulling in EmailTemplates from the desired folder.